If building a DIY screw jack, would it be beneficial to add a gimbal to the jack nut, and/or to the screw attachment?

The screw jack will be used twice daily.
It will be made out of M24 8.8 grade threaded rod and nut.
The nut will travel 300mm, to raise a weight of 50kg by 800m, via a pivoting lever arm.
The parts will be greased and shrouded.

Would putting the nut (and or the screw) on gimbals be beneficial, unnecessary, or maybe even detrimental?
My reasoning was that it would eliminate all forces in all the unwanted directions. And so it would spread the weight evenly over the contact area of the nut threads. Hopefully reducing wear and increasing the reliability and lifespan.
Alternatively, would it be better to add pivots along one axis (instead of an entire gimbal), while ensuring that the pivots are in adjacent directions between the nut and the screw attachment (handle end)?
This is the gimbal I'm thinking of making from mild steel:
https://ctrl.vi/i/iBGsLuc3M

What about a bearing between nut and load or is it ok for the load to rotate? Or do you just accept the friction?

Sorry I think my description might have been off a bit. But it works more similar to a bench vise than a screw jack I think. Or like almost exactly like this: https://ctrl.vi/i/rcy08wOlI
